# how to append and remove field using class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a form for product sale. admin can add fields for multiple product's click on add button using jquery and can remove fields by clicking on remove button.
I'm trying to append this using `div` id but this doesn't work. in this image, mark area will append by every clicking on add new row button.

[image: Here is my image]

```
<div class="row" id="dsf">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <select name="p_name" class="form-control" id="p_name">
                                <option value="">-Select Product-</option>
                                @foreach($products as $product)
                                <option value="{{$product->product_id}}">{{$product->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" name="p_code" id="p_code" class="form-control" readonly="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" name="unit_pctn" id="unit_pctn" class="form-control" readonly="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" name="u_price" id="u_price" class="form-control" readonly="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <input type="text" name="ctn" id="ctn" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <input type="text" name="pcs" id ="pcs" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" name="t_amt" id="t_amt" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div id="temp"></div>

                    </div>
```

here is jquery part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elm=$(".dsf");
    $("#addrow").click(function(){
        $("#dsf").append();
    });
});
```

Comment: can you give us the code

Comment: you should show html :))

Comment: code part are given. now.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```js
 function addRow(tableID) {
 
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 
 var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
 var element1 = document.createElement("input");
 element1.type = "checkbox";
 element1.name="chkbox[]";
 cell1.appendChild(element1);
 
 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
 cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;
 
 var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
 var element2 = document.createElement("input");
 element2.type = "text";
 element2.name = "txtbox[]";
 cell3.appendChild(element2);
 
 
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
 try {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  
  for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
   var row = table.rows[i];
   var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
   if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
    table.deleteRow(i);
    rowCount--;
    i--;
   }
   
   
  }
 }catch(e) {
  alert(e);
 }
}
```

```html
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

 <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

 <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px">
  <TR>
   <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
   <TD> 1 </TD>
   <TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD>
  </TR>
 </TABLE>
```